# How can I update transition-delay value via ReactJS Component?

Tags: css, reactjs, setstate

I am writing a ReactJS component for the first time. I have a tooltip which needs to have a dynamic delay value on mouseenter and mouseleave events. I am currently using a hover approach in CSS with transition-delay. This solution is working for me however, I need to be able to setState and update each of the transition-delay (see below) through my component. I need to be able to accomplish this with pure ReactJS/Javascript (no JQuery etc).

Here is a sample of my code:

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 120px;
background-color: #555;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 5px 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;
opacity: 0;
transition-delay: 2s;
```

}

```
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
transition-delay: 1s;
```

}

How can I access each of these transition-delay properties from the component and change the value with setState?

Thanks for your help

**Update**: I have figured out how to update the CSS property through JS. I now need to be able to reset the state. Please see my comment from below.
Here is some additional code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  userInput: '',
  transitionDelay: '0s'
} 
  handleMouseEnterDelay() {
   var mouseIn = document.getElementById('tooltip');
   var delayIn = mouseIn.style.transitionDelay = '0s';    
   this.setState({
    transitionDelay: {delayIn}
   })          
  }

  handleMouseLeaveDelay() {
   var mouseLeave = document.getElementById('tooltiptext');
   var delayLeave = mouseLeave.style.transitionDelay = '4s';
   this.setState({
     transitionDelay: {delayLeave}
   })
```

So what I need is that after each hover event i need transitionDelay to take the values defined in the function. I.e. after first mouseenter/leave event it stays to 4s, so the second time I go to hover(enter) then it is a 4s delay for both enter and leave. I need the enter delay to go back to 0s as defined in the handleMouseEnterDelay function.

Is there a way which I can have two 'transitionDelay' values in setState? I tried a nested object i.e. in:{transitionDelay}, out:{transitionDelay} but i couldn't access it while setting state.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like...

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    style: {
      transitionDelay: '1s'
    }
  };

  this.toggleDelay = this.toggleDelay.bind(this);
}

toggleDelay(state) {
  this.setState({ style: { transitionDelay: state ? '2s' : '1s' } });
}
...

render() {
  return (
    <div className="tooltip" style={this.state.style} onMouseEnter={() => this.toggleDelay(true)} onMouseLeave={() => this.toggleDelay(false)}>
     .....
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks @Emir. I tried your solution but it didn't work. I figured out how to update the property value using  var element = document.getElementById('tooltiptext'), element.style.transitionDelay = '4s'; However, it is getting applied to both mouseenter and leave functions. Also, this new value only kicks off on the second hover

Comment: For example, i have set mouseenter transitionDelay to 1s then in mouseleave function I am again setting state for transitionDelay to 4s. So when I go back to hover the 4s delay is set for both enter and leave. I need it to take the value which is defined in the mouseenter function again. I.e. from 4s it needs to go back to 1s then when leave function is called the value again needs to be 4s. I need it to keep resetting its value to what is defined in the respective functions.